# CDN for a pre-existing backend service

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cdn

How can I Enable Cloud CDN for a pre-existing backend service. and Enable load balancing services in google cloud platform.

Answer (score 0):

Enable Cloud CDN for a pre-existing backend service - https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/quickstart

Comment: Thank for your reply.

Comment: I followed quick start documentation, but In my load balancing page Enable Cloud CDN check box is not showing up. Please help me why it is not showing?

Answer (score 0):

select the name of your load balancer in which you want to enable cdn, then select the back-end service in that which ever you want(the one in for which u want to enable cdn) then at the bottom you will see a check box,just tick it.